# Export overleaf V1 to V2

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf

When I open the new overleaf (V2), I have some projects tagged as "V1".
The question is: how should I convert/export those to V2?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the title it should open a box that asks if you want to move the project to v2.

[image: image of Overleaf message box]

The message reads:

> Warning: Some Overleaf v1 features aren't supported yet
>
> We are still working hard to bring some Overleaf v1 features to the v2
>   editor. In v2:
>
> - **Direct git access to your projects** is not yet available, but you can migrate your project to the Overleaf v2 GitHub integration Read
>     More.
> - There are **no Zotero and CiteULike** integrations yet
> - Some **Journals and Services in the Submit menu** don't support direct submissions yet
>
> **Please note: you cannot move this project back to v1 once you have
>   moved it to v2.**
>
> Are you sure you want to move (*project title*) into Overleaf v2?

Note that there are some features that aren't yet supported in v2 and you can't switch back, but if you are sure you want to switch over then just click on the "yes move project to v2" button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I do not see any box popping up. I am afraid that it must be because I am not the owner of the project.

Comment: @elachell Since the export can't be undone, it's likely you're right.

Comment: WHAT DOES "click on the title" mean? There is no place to click.